# ZipFile can't extract a zip with directories

Tags: python, zip

I'm trying to unzip files in Python. I'm using the following function:

```
def unzip(source_filename, dest_dir):
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(source_filename)
    for member in zf.infolist():
        # Path traversal defense copied from
        # http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/http/server.py#l789
        words = filter(None, member.filename.split('/'))
        path = dest_dir
        for word in words[:-1]:
            drive, word = os.path.splitdrive(word)
            head, word = os.path.split(word)
            if word in (os.curdir, os.pardir): continue
            path = os.path.join(path, word)
        zf.extract(member, path)
```

When unzipping a .zip with a directory called "gui", I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MCManager.py", line 137, in add
    unzip(addedFilepath, dirUnzipped)
  File "MCManager.py", line 19, in unzip
    zf.extract(member, path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/zipfile.py", line 928, in extract
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/zipfile.py", line 962, in _extract_member
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/Users/student/Library/Application Support/minecraft/temp/unzipped/gui/gui'
```

Is this a problem with ZipFile()?

Comment: Does `/Users/student/Library/Application Support/minecraft/temp/unzipped/gui` even exist? If so, is `/Users/student/Library/Application Support/minecraft/temp/unzipped/gui/gui` a directory?

Comment: @nneonneo It turns out that when I unzip it with a normal zip utility, "gui" is a directory with a .png inside, but my script was creating an empty file with that name.

Comment: Yes, it seems any time the zip contains a directory, I get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extract) for the method `extract`, you will find that the `path` variable that is received by your method through the variable `dest_dir` must be the path to a dir which you want the contents of the zip files you iterate to be extracted to.

As you have stated on you question, `gui` is a file, not a directory. And to be completely honest, you statement

> When unzipping a .zip with a file called "gui (...)"

doesn't make very much sense.

Additionally, you may want to take a look at the [`os.mkdir`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.mkdir) method, so that you can create directories on demand.

Comment: I am feeding the function the path of a .zip file, and a nonexistent directory, which it seems to create as normal. Not sure what you meant by "doesn't make very much sense", but I meant the .zip file, when decompressed, creates a file named "gui", though I now know it's a directory then unzipped with a normal utility.

Comment: Ok, so I tested your code an it uncompressed a zip file successfully. Could you please tell us the dir your are running the script from, and the arguments you are passing to the unzip method? Thanks!

Comment: did the zip contain a directory?

Comment: I'm running the script from `/Users/student/Desktop`, with my terminal's pwd at desktop. I am passing the unzip method `addedFilepath`, a string equal to "/Users/student/Desktop/SpawnerGUI.zip", and `dirUnzipped`, a string equal to "/Users/student/Library/Application Support/minecraft/temp/unzipped"; `...Support/minecraft/temp` is a directory that exists, `...Support/minecraft/temp/unzipped` does not exist.

Comment: Would you mind checking if the folder which has the .PNG's in the zip file, also has a `.DS_Store` file in it?

Comment: Yes, it does... Is that the problem?

Comment: when unzip it with a proper utility, remove the .DS_Store, rezip it, and try again with the script, it now gives me `OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/Users/student/Library/Application Support/minecraft/temp/unzipped/__MACOSX/__MACOSX'`

Comment: Try to skip both files while you iterate over the list.

Comment: Put `if words[-1] == '.DS_Store' or words[-1] == '__MACOSX': continue`  before `path = dest_dir`

Comment: I've done some more experimenting, and here's what I've determined: Zips with a single file, multiple files, or a mix of files and folders are all fine, UNLESS there is actually anything in the folder. I have tried every combination, and there is no other possibility. The .DS_Store/__MACOSX files also caused problems, but the if...continue line solved that. The only remaining question (until I manage to run into 12 more problems) is why the files in directories cause problems.

Comment: I downloaded your Zip file and it successfully unzipped your file (the if...continue was not present). The only think I can think of now is a permission-related issue.

Comment: Even when the zip and destination directory are 777, it isn't working... Could you post the exact script you are using?

Comment: It is exactly the one you posted. It was a simple copy&paste followed by the insertion of `import os` and `import zipfile`.

Comment: And you fed it a zip file and a nonexistent directory?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18070/discussion-between-arturhoo-and-tkbx)